# Array formula to return match based on date criteria

Tags: arrays, excel

The following codes works great for me when my data is stored in row 2 and below. But if my array range is from row 6 and below, how do I adapt the formula?
Thanks in advance

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Array_Range,SMALL(IF(Health_Check_Date<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-2,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),ROW(Health_Check_Date)),ROW($1:$1)),1)),"",INDEX(Array_Range,SMALL(IF(Health_Check_Date<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-2,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),ROW(Health_Check_Date)),ROW($1:$1)),1))
```

Named Ranges:
Array_Range = $A$6:$B$9
Health_Check_Date = B$6$:$B$9

Sample Data (From row 5 onwards)

```
A       B
Test1   18/05/2015
Test2   15/05/2015
Test3   19/05/1991
Test4   18/05/2013
```

Comment: Is it `Health_Check_Date<DATE(...` or `Health_Check_Date<=DATE(...` ?

Comment: Without some small redacted representation of sample data the references to your named ranges are meaningless. Further, your formula would be easier to understand if chopped down to something like `=IFERROR(INDEX(Array_Range, SMALL(IF(Health_Check_Date<EDATE(TODAY(), -24), ROW(Health_Check_Date), ROW($1:$1)), 1)), "")`.

Comment: Hi - it's the first of the two, just <

Comment: Post updated to include data samples and named range references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your data started in row 2, you were actually offsetting by one row down. This problem was magnified when you shifted the data down to start in row 6. This is due to the difference of returning the worksheet row and the *row position within* a named range. If *Health_Check_Date* refers to B6:B9 then wrapping the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) around a match on the first row is going to return a *6*, not a *1*. You need to adjust hte return by the starting row of *Health_Check_Date*.

Your formula was designed to return the first, second, third, etc matches into successive row but you had locked this out with the absolute addresses in `ROW($1:$1)`. I've removed that restriction.

The [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) is a more efficient way to knock a couple years off today.

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) reduces the doubling up of the formula that an `IF(ISERROR(...` requires by evaluating the formula and returning the default if it is in error ot the formula's result if it is not.

[image: Small Index Array_Range]

The *array formula* in D1 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Array_Range, SMALL(IF(Health_Check_Date<EDATE(TODAY(), -24), ROW(Health_Check_Date)-ROW(INDEX(Health_Check_Date, 1, 1))+1), ROW(1:1)), 1), "")
```

If blank cells in *Health_Check_Date* need to be discarded, stack an extra `IF` into the works that ignores zero length.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Array_Range, SMALL(IF(LEN(Health_Check_Date), IF(Health_Check_Date<EDATE(TODAY(), -24), ROW(Health_Check_Date)-ROW(INDEX(Health_Check_Date, 1, 1))+1)), ROW(1:1)), 1), "")
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> (but you knew that!). Fill down for subsequent returns.

Comment: Thank you! Just so I understand the formula, how would you amend if column B was one column over, in C? 
So named ranges:
Array_Range = $A$6:$C$9 
Health_Check_Date = C$6$:$C$9

Comment: Since *Health_Check_Date* is a defined range, it shouldn't matter if it is one column over; only that it is parallel with and the same number of rows as *Array_Range*.

Comment: One last question - how would you amend so the formula ignores blank cells?